# Timeout by attaching a process in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, process, timeout

I am creating a webpage in Visual Studio 2005, and I attach that project to a process like Firefox or whatever. If I create a breakpoint in the code (for example to a click event), and I am too much time looking at the code, suddenly the process unattach and I cannot continue looking the code.

**Question**: Does anyone know how to increase the waiting time when you associate a web page to a browser?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1) In IIS 7.5, right click on the application pool that your app is running under and click on "Advanced Settings"

2) Under the "Process Model" section, set "Ping Enabled" to false